# Are Sylow theorems true for subgroups smaller than ${\rm Syl}_p(G)$?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

For example, if $|G|= 5^7\cdot3$ can I use the Sylow theorems on the subgroup with order $5^2$?

I don't think I can, but I can't find a counter example, can someone provide one?

Comment: Not following.  The Sylow theorems hold for any finite group.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: As Sylow groups are $p$-groups (groups with order a power of a prime), the claim the Sylow theorem makes for it is however somewhat trivial.

Comment: @lulu I think I am very clear on what I am asking, even provide an example, all over the world people teach these things slightly different,  $Syl_5(G)=5^7$, and I am asking if I can use those theorems for a subgroup like $5^2$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen they didn't teach me that way, that's why I am asking

Comment: *NB:* ${\rm Syl}_p(G)$ is the set of all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$; it has no subgroups since it is not a group.

Comment: @Shaun the set of all subgroups with order $p^n$ where $n$ is the biggest possible integer

Comment: Yes, what I have written is equivalent to what you have. But you say in the title, "subgroups of ${\rm Syl}_p(G)$".

Comment: Just asserting that what you wrote is clear does not make it so.  For a general group $G$, $Syl_p(G)$ is not itself a group, it's just a set.  And writing "a subgroup like $5^2$" does not make sense.  That's a number, not a group.

Comment: What do you mean by, "subgroups smaller than ${\rm Syl}_p(G)$"?

Comment: @Shaun I got confused, your answer isn't answering what I am asking thought

Comment: Well, I have answered it as it is written. If you mean something else, please ask in a separate thread.

Comment: @Shaun we have a group with order $5^7 3 $ can I use the sylow theorems on the subgroup $5^2$ ?

Comment: Yes. My answer explains why, just slightly more generally.

Comment: @Shaun but the subgroup of order $5^2$ isn't in the set $Syl_5(G)$

Comment: Ah, yes; I see now. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion in the comments here. @lupusnox, are you perhaps asking whether Sylow’s theorems can tell us anything about the existence or number of subgroups of $G$ of order $5^2$ in your example? For example: Is there guaranteed to be a subgroup of order $5^2$? (And of course the general cases of these questions).

Comment: @Milten we know it exist a subgroup of order $5^2$ by the 1st theorem, I was asking if I could use the other theorems of sylow like the 2nd on a group which isn't in the set $Syl_p(G)$, I was confused because my first thought was Shaun's answer and didn't realize that now the element $g$ s.t $gKg^{-1}=N$ where $K,N$ is in $Syl_p(H)$ and $H\leq G$ will be in $H$ not $G$, and I thought that would be a problem, ends up it isn't, I was just confused about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $H\le G$ for a group $G$, if $G$ is finite, so is $H$; moreover: $H$ is itself a group. Thus Sylow's theorems apply to $H$.

Comment: @lulu If we use the sylow theorems on $H$ and get that a subgroup $\in Syl_p(H)$ is normal in $H$, then it's normal in $G$ also ?